# Nexus 7 not rendering in Eclipse

Tags: android, nexus-7

My layout has been rendering fine on all test cases in the Eclipse GUI editor including all Google devices. I just updated the SDK from 22 to 22.0.1 and now I'm told:

> It looks like you are using a render target where the layout library
>   does not support the tvdpi density.

I have these specific resource folders:

```
drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
values
values-large-hdpi
values-large-mdpi
values-large-xhdpi
values-large-mdpi
values-large-xhdpi
values-xlarge
```

I've tried adding tvdpi and large-tvdpi resources but that doesn't fix the problem. I'm targeting API 8. What has caused Nexus 7 rendering to break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had

```
    <uses-sdk:android:targetSdkVersion="8">
```

in the manifest which threw it out. This value isn't necessary, or should be set as high as the highest API level you have tested to.

Edit: Also, select a high enough API in Eclipse layout editor - the green Android robot icon with an API number next to it. You need an API that features TVDPI.